# Serverless Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, serverless

When I send an API request, I'm getting this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost3000/auth. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

I'm using React for the frontend and serverless for the backend. I tried a few different solutions but none have worked so far. I added a `headers` property to the return value of my handler like this:

```
async function intentHandler(event, intents) {
  const request = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const intent = intents[request.intent];
  const response = intent
    ? { status: 200, payload: await intent({ ...request.payload }) }
    : { status: 404, payload: "Invalid intent." };

  return {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, 
    },
    statusCode: response.status,
    body: JSON.stringify(response.payload),
  };
}
```

I also have this in my `serverless.yml` file:

```
  allowedOrigins:
    - http://localhost:2020
    - http://localhost:3000
```

Note: the page gets reloaded quickly while the error message appears.

Comment: Heya, in your serverless.yml add "cors: true" to your handler function please and see if that works?

Comment: also just use, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true while we're debugging this ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry and allow-methods: '*' just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Should the last two go in the yml file or the handler?

Comment: cors:true goes under the function in serverless.yml and then return just those two headers in your function also, Cors:true configures API gateway, the return from the function covers the api itself.